# Book of short stories, illustrated, space theme 1950s/60s, aimed at children

Tags: story-identification, space

I remember illustrations showing a man in space holding a generator towing an electrical cable which attracted the worm-like serpents away from the space ship.

Another story showed our heroes under attack from aliens looking remarkably like stylized red Indians astride vehicles looking like motor cycles.

I remember it being a hard backed large format book. I originally thought it was Dan Dare but all my searches just turn up the comic series.
Hope you can help

Comment: It's probably no help but I had the same book with wonderful illustrations inside front and back covers Moon base under domes, egg-shaped robots in spaceships that looked like dragonflies. FTL flight through rings in space. First time I've come across someone else who remembers it! The heroes looked like Dan Dare and Digby.